# Kentico 9 - Apply sorting on content tree based on custom field

Tags: sorting, tree, kentico

In Kentico 9, need guidance to achieve following scenario:

I have a custom page type like "Appointments" in which I have a custom fields with name "AppointmentDate". I have created a folder into content tree with name "All appointments" , under that created some folder for years like 2016,2015, etc.

Now when I add an "Appointment" type under a year folder like "2016", I need ti should be insert Order by "AppointmentDate" in tree. Like follows

```
- All Appointments
---- 2016
-------- Ap1  (AppointmentDate fields = 5 May 2016)
-------- Ap2   (AppointmentDate fields = 6 Jun 2016)
--------- Ap3   (AppointmentDate fields = 25 Jun 2016)
```

So if now add new appointment with name like "App4" where set "AppointmentDate fields = 11 Jun 2016", so it should be insert between Ap2 and Ap3 under content tree in Admin panel.

Hope I am clear with my query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can [attach](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Handling+global+events) to global event

```
DocumentEvents.Create.After += Document_Create_After;
```

and in document create after method check for the path of your page and desired page type. If it`s node you need to order (is in proper subtree, is kind of proper page type etc.) just use

```
 CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeProvider.MoveNodeDown
```

or

```
 CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeProvider.MoveNodeUp
```

depending on your field and ordering requirements.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your quick reply.
I am aware with attaching global event, but confuse how to apply sorting on tree nodes to make is order by specific field or how to insert new node to either above or below to specified now.

Also regarding to  "CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeProvider.MoveNodeDown" API, seems removed in K9 from TreeProvider class. as getting only this method under DocumentHelper class "DocumentHelper.MoveDocument(newnode, targetnode);"  

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You may be able to use CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeProvider.SetNodeOrder Method (TreeNode, Int32)  and just find out how many Appointments have a date earlier than the new document (if there are 3 newer appointments, then set the node order to 3).  I am not sure if the order is 0 based or not, i would think so but it may be 1 based, so you may need to test and adjust!

Comment: Sorry for my late answer - Trevor is right - this is the only one approach I am familiar with to achieve your desired behavior, thank you Travor  for the clarification.